# Medicine and chemical density related

Tags: density

How are medicine densities calculated?For example what is the density of ascorbic acid 0f 250mg a pill?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's your problem.

Comment: I agree with @Mithoron. It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ascorbic Acid will have a density of 1.69 g/cm³ (I couldn't find under what conditions, however). If you are asking how to calculate the density of a mixture (be it homogeneous or heterogeneous), there are several chemical engineering books that deal with the subject matter. However, it doesn't make sense to ask about the density of ascorbic acid in a 250 mg pill. You could say that it is the mass of the ascorbic acid divided by the volume of the pill. But then, the "density" loses its meaning. Why? because it is possible to make any material have some density that we want by varying the volume of the container and the mass of the molecule/atom/compound (we could place one atom of any element in a container of humongous volume such that the density is near zero). Density is a description of how molecules/atoms/ions attract each other through intermolecular forces (with the pressure/temperature specified).